# How do I run a change event after dynamically updating a value in a form using JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Each time my form is updated, multiple calculations are run. This is within an on change event listener:

```
form.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
```

I want a button that resets the value of a field in the form, then updates the calculations. The click function below changes the value but doesnt update the form calculations. I wrapped my on change event in a function, then called it within the onclick, but didnt work. Is there a way to trigger a form change using an on click like below?

```
$("#s2q12_reset").click(function(){
  $("#s2q12").val(0);
});
```

Comment: It's odd to mix code hooking up event handlers directly with the DOM and code doing it with jQuery. I suggest using one or the other, rather than both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet here by far is to move the code doing the calculations into its own function, and then call that function from the `change` handler and from your `click` handler (after changing the value):

```
function updateCalculations() {
    // ...
}

// If all that your `change` event does is that, you can use the funttion directly:
form.addEventListener('change', updateCalculations);

$("#s2q12_reset").click(function(){
    $("#s2q12").val(0);
    updateCalculations();
});
```

As a very-much-second-best solution, you can trigger the `change` event after updating the value via `form.change()`.